# .htaccess causing 500 internal server errors

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'd like to protect a directory in my `uploads` folder in wordpress located at `http://site.com/wp-content/uploads/assets`, so I tried adding an `.htaccess` to the `assets` folder with the following code:

```
Options All -Indexes
<FilesMatch ".(htaccess|mustache)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

My `assets` folder contains subfolders as well, which include css and image files. I'm trying to restrict access from browsing the directory and directly accessing my `.mustache` template files.

However, the CSS will not load, producing a 500 error when trying to link to it on my page.

Example structure:

```
/assets
    template.mustache
    image.jpg
    file.php

    media/
        style.css
        script.js
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Not that it should matter but FilesMatch accepts regex so your first dot ought to be `\.` to prevent matching any char, i.e. `.`. Now you'r problem isn't really matching too much but anyway :)

Comment: Look in the error log to see what the actual 500 error is.